# XMPP chat app architecture suggestion

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I have a chat app having web service installed on tomcat server, `ejabberd` as XMPP server. Right now i am using `strophe.js` on client side to directly communicate with ejabberd server for chatting purpose.

Is this correct chat app design ? or shall I send chat through tomcat server so that xmpp server is not accessible directly from client side ? Can anyon suggest a better design ?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your clients directly to ejabberd (or through a proxy like NGinx). ejabberd is designed to receive lot of traffic directly and using Tomcat as proxy will not be scalable and is not recommended.